# how to upload multiple location data in parse.com?

Tags: parse-platform, geopoints

I have a 100 data contains location name, it's latitude, and it's longitude. The data is stored in csv file.

I need to upload it to my apps database in parse.com

is there any tutorial on how to do it?
I'm using macbook as my PC by the way.

Comment: Do you need to do this through the app? Parse has a built in import function that can take a csv. Just on the website.

Comment: I doesn't have to be through the app. Unfortunately, parse seems not allowing importing data location (geopoints) from csv.

Comment: If you put them in a plush it wouldn't take long to create a utility app to load them into an array and save them up to parse.